# get everything inside/between html tags

Tags: php, regex, xpath

what is the best way to get some html elements + values? example:

```
<div id="abc" class="classs">
    <img src="pic1.png" alt="pico">
    <img src="pic2.png" alt="nano">
</div>
```

what I have is the **id=abc** of the div element.
I want to get everything inside the div element like:

```
class of the div ("classs")
src of the pictures and other data:
src="pic1.png", alt="pico"
src="pic2.png", alt="nano"
```

it should be in an array, object or something.
What would you prefer? xpath? regex? xmlobject?

Comment: Is there a possibility to use XHTML? That would make it easier to use XML-based solutions.

Comment: Do you want to do this server-side or client-side?

Comment: server side and yes, i can use xhtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
public function innerHTML($DOMnode) {
    return preg_replace(
        '/^<(\w+)\b.*?>(.*)<\/\1?>/s',
        '$2',
        $DOMnode->ownerDocument->saveXML($DOMnode)
    );
}
```

Comment: IA IA Cthulhu Fhtagn!!! http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: if you studied the code better, you'd notice you're not parsing the entire HTML page, but only the contents of the DOM node!

Comment: I did study it and found it horrible to convert the DomNode to string in order to be able to run a Regex on it.

Comment: I see no reason why using strings would be less efficient than iterating over nodes and using appendXML and document fragments

Comment: Because it's like switching from a scalpell to a spoon during surgery. If you are already using the right toolset (DOM), why abandon it when you are halfway through for one that has no clue about nodes and attributes?